# Why is the same value being saved into my table regardless of which select option I select?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm adding a row/record to a table; one of the values saved, which is supposed to represent which of two options were selected from a select element, is always saved as "0" - whether I select the first option (at index 0) or the second option (at index 1).

Here is the code:

```
Dim Subcategory As String 
. . .
If Request.Form.Item("Action") = "Save" Then
    Unit = Request.Form.Item("Unit")
    CustNo = Request.Form.Item("CustNo")
    Subcategory = Request.Form.Item("selectSubcategory").ToString()
. . 
Dim query2 As String = String.Empty
query2 &= "UPDATE Customers "
query2 &= "SET Subcategory = @SubCat "
query2 &= "WHERE MemberNo = @MemberNo AND Unit = @Unit AND CustNo = @CustNo "

Using conn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=PROSQL05;DATABASE=cpsdata;UID=sa;PWD=sqlsql")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query2
            .Parameters.Add("@MemberNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MemberNo
            .Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Unit
            .Parameters.Add("@CustNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CustNo
            .Parameters.Add("@Subcat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Subcategory
        End With
        conn.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 'comm
End Using 'conn           
. . .
<select name="selectSubcategory" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">
    <% If Not IsNewBusiness Then%>
        <option <% If Subcategory = "0" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="0">Existing
        <option <% If Subcategory = "1" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="1">Organic Growth
    <% Else%>
        <option <% If Subcategory = "0" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="0">New
        <option <% If Subcategory = "1" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="1">Assumed
    <% End If%>
</select>
```

Unit and CustNo are being stored exactly as I enter them (string values in text boxes), but Subcategory is always 0.

In the test scenario, the Existing and Organic Growth are the two options that display in the "selectSubcategory" select element. Whether I choose "Organic Growth" or "Existing", 0 is written to the database.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please stop writing *stringly-typed* code. Do you really believe that "string" is the correct data type for your parameters?

Comment: What do you mean? That is the underlying type in the database for these values (VarChar)

Comment: You have at least two parameters that,  by their names, suggest that they are *numbers*. You should be representing them in your code as numbers, they should be stored in the database as numbers, the transfer between these places should use numbers, etc.

Comment: Theoretically, you have a point, but the database was designed untold years ago, my last day here and my last day programming is a week away, and I'm not going to change those things now.