# How can I retrieve the string value of the selected select element item?

Tags: vb.net, html-select

A previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283374/why-is-the-same-value-being-saved-into-my-table-regardless-of-which-select-optio) is related.

What I find I really need to know, though, is something more specific, namely, how can I retrieve the string value of the selected select element item?

This is what I'm using to grab the value:

```
Subcategory = Request.Form.Item("selectSubcategory").ToString()
```

...but it's always assigning "0" to Subcategory, no matter which item is selected.

Here is everywhere "Subcategory" appears in the code:

Declared:

```
Dim Subcategory As String
```

Assigned (as shown above):

```
Subcategory = Request.Form.Item("selectSubcategory").ToString()
```

Database Write:

```
query2 &= "SET Subcategory = @SubCat "
. . .
.Parameters.Add("@Subcat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Subcategory
```

Select element code:

```
<select name="selectSubcategory" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">
    <% If Not IsNewBusiness Then%>
        <option <% If Subcategory = "0" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="0">Existing
        <option <% If Subcategory = "1" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="1">Organic Growth
    <% Else%>
        <option <% If Subcategory = "0" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="0">New
        <option <% If Subcategory = "1" Then Response.Write(" selected")%> value="1">Assumed
    <% End If%>
</select>
```

Why is "0" always assigned to Subcategory? How can I assign the selected item's text value instead?

### UPDATE

Based on other things I have read, I thought maybe I needed to decorate the select element with the "runat="server"" jazz. But when I did that, like so:

```
<select name="selectSubcategory" runat="server" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">
```

I got this:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Source Error: 

Line 767:                                        </td>
Line 768:                                        <td nowrap align="left" valign="top">
Line 769:                                            <select name="selectSubcategory" runat="server" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">
Line 770:                                            <%--<asp:dropdownlist name="selectSubcategory" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">--%>
Line 771:                                                <% If Not IsNewBusiness Then%>

Source File: /EMS/pages/custmaint_entry.aspx    Line: 769
```

To paraphrase the Pulitzer-prize-winning hero of Hibbing,

### UPDATE 2

It happened again; with no changes to the code (or, more precisely, trying everything under the sun and then reverting back to what was originally tried, which didn't work before), now it works. Las Campanas del Infierno!

I still or am back to having this:

```
Subcategory = Request.Form.Item("selectSubcategory").ToString()
```

...and this:

```
<select name="selectSubcategory" color="<%=Session("TextColor")%>" style="font: 8pt arial" onchange="UpdateFlag=true;">
```

...and now at works, whereas it didn't before.

I can't tell y'all how glad I am to be getting out of programming; I don't think I could stand more than another week of this. Burned out? I'm charred to a smoldering crisp.

Comment: lol i guess you are never programming again, yeah? btw is your issue solved? too much information here

Comment: See Update 2. I may eventually write some utilities for my own use; I can definitely see myself doing that. Probably not next week or next month, though.